# Connecting SQL client to an Oracle Amazon RDS instance

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, toad, sql-workbench-j

Does someone know how to access an Oracle Amazon RDS instance via any SQL client such as "SQL workbench" or "Toad"? Is it necessary a JDBC? Thank you in advance. Cheers!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: JDBC does not need an Oracle client. All you need is the driver .jar file

Comment: With SQL Workbench being a JDBC based client (like SQL Developer) you only need the Oracle JDBC driver which can be downloaded from Oracle:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: Thanks for the correction - I've deleted my misleading comment and learnt something new. Do you still need orahome, tnsnames, all that horrible stuff though?

Comment: Thank you for your help! My JDBC URL starts like that: "jdbc:redshift://....." which made me download the redshift JDBC. I downloaded SQL Workbench as well. Eventually, the problem is that I'm still not able to connect.
My connection details are:
Driver: Redshift (com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver)
URL: jdbc:redshift://*****.*******.ap-southeast-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/******
Username: *****
Password: *****